# Algebraic square root question

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

As part of working with dot products of vectors in an algebraic field, having previously solved the algebraic quotient, I need to find the algebraic square root as shown in (1)

Let $r_i$ be a root of polynomial P and $s_j$ be a root of polynomial Q i.e., P($r_i$)=0, Q($s_j$)=0.

I seek to find a third polynomial R and its root $t_k$, such that R($t_k$)=0, so that

(1) $t_k$ = $\sqrt{1 - r_i^2 - s_j^2}$

is satisfied. How can R be found, knowing $t_k$?

Comment: r = P(i) and s = Q(j) isn't abusing notation; that's just bad notation.  

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma 1:**  If $P(x)$ is an integer polynomial with root $r$, then $P(x^2)$ is an integer polynomial with root $\sqrt{r}$.

**Lemma 2:**  If $P(x)$ is an integer polynomial with root $r$, then $P(\sqrt{x})P(-\sqrt{x})$ is an integer polynomial with root $r^2$.

**Lemma 3:**  If $P(x)$ is an integer polynomial with root $r$, then $P(x - t)$ is an integer polynomial with root $r + t$, for $t$ an integer.

**Lemma 4:**  If $P, Q$ are integer polynomials with roots $r, s$, then an integer polynomial with root $r + s$ is given by the characteristic polynomial of $A \otimes I + I \otimes B$ where $A, B$ are the [companion matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $P, Q$ and $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  Multiplication by $r + s$ defines a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear transformation on $\mathbb{Q}[r, s]$, which has $\mathbb{Q}$-basis $r^i s^j$ where $i, j$ range from $0$ to one less than the degrees of $P$ and $q$, and the matrix above is the matrix of this linear transformation in that basis.

So apply Lemma 2 twice, then Lemma 3, then Lemma 4, then Lemma 1.

Comment: Considering that I am working with 864 degree polynomials, and that there doesn't appear to be an easy way of implementing Lemma 2 in GP-Pari, this will take awhile, but I accept your answer.

Comment: I am having problems with Lemma 4, in general the Kronecker product of A,I is not the same size matrix as I,B, so I cannot add the matrices.  Furthermore, working with the Kronecker product of 864th degree polynomials is proving impractical in GP-Pari, due to both time and memory constraints, so is there a resultant method which might work better?  I do need to keep the matrices with multiple precision entries down to a reasonable size.


Comment: Can you not just give the smaller polynomial 0 coefficients to make the matrices the same size?

Comment: Sorry, that was ambiguous.  The first I is of dimension deg Q and the second I is of dimension deg P.  Anyway, maybe you should just use Wiedemann's algorithm (http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/modform/modform/linear_algebra.html#sec-wiedemann) on the action of r+s on Q[r, s] directly instead.  

Comment: I actually took the time to implement the resultant method, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant on this, particularly their paragraph under the heading Applications which states:

If x and y are algebraic numbers such that P(x) = Q(y) = 0 (with degree of Q=n), we see that z = x + y is a root of the resultant (in x) of P(x) and Q(z − x) and that t = xy is a root of the resultant of P(x) and xnQ(t / x) ; combined with the fact that 1 / y is a root of ynQ(1 / y), this shows that the set of algebraic numbers is a field.

It is much easy to work with matrices size m+n than size m*n.

Comment: It depends on the implementation, but the Kronecker-product matrices should be sparse, so the dimension is not always a worry.

Comment: I finally was able to recover all the algebraic points, but several polynomial equations of degree 1728 (and containing coefficients of around 10^700) had to be factored.

The longest time was spent taking the determinant of the resultant matrix.

The highest power that occurred in the answer was 144.